# WPF DataGrid: Remove internal scrollviewer from datagrid without distorting ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controltemplate

Please i need some on how to remove the internal scrollviewer from the DataGrid's controltemplate in wpf. Below is the ControlTemplate containing the ScrollViewer. Any idea on how to remove the scrollviewer and the scrollbars from the template without destroying the functionality of the datagrid?

I have a custom scrollbar that i have designed to use in my app so the internal scrollviewer in the datagrid wouldn't allow me to do smooth scrolling. Leaving me with two choices. Either i remove the internal scrollviewer from the datagrid control template that i will post below or i remove my custom scrollbars. I want to keep my custom scrollbar so i need help in removing the one in the control template. 
 i have tried to replace the ScrollviewerControl with a StackPanel and then remove the scrollbars completely but i get an error message saying

> The member "Template" is not recognized or is not accessible

Any help will be appreciated

Here is the Control template i want to modify

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="False">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" Focusable="False" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                <Button.Visibility>
                                    <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <DataGridHeadersVisibility>All</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </Button.Visibility>
                            </Button>
                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1">
                                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                    <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <DataGridHeadersVisibility>Column</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                            </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```